# Vue: how to assert with sinon spy that component method was called

Tags: vue.js, sinon, spy, sinon-chai

I have a singe page component:

```html
<template>
  ...
  <button
    id="some-button"
    @click="clicked"
  >
    Button
  </button>
  ...
</template>
...
export default {
  name: 'MyComponent',
  ...
  methods: {
    fetchRequest: async function () {
    ...
    }
    clicked: async function () {
      ...

      this.fetchRequest()
    }
    ...
```

And my test:

```js
it('should fetch after clicking on that specific button', async () => {
  const spyFetchRequest = sinon.spy()

  wrapper = createWrapper(MyComponent, {
    provide() { return { repository: testRepository }},
    mocks: {
      fetchRequest: spyFetchRequest,
    },
  })

  await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 0))

  await wrapper.get('#some-button').trigger('click')

  expect(spyFetchRequest.calledOnce).to.be.true
})
```

However I get `false` instead:

```sh
AssertionError: expected false to be true
+ expected - actual

-false
+true
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `mocks` mounting option is not intended to mock component methods. That's for mocking global instance properties (e.g., `$router` or `$store`).

To mock a component method, use `sinon.spy()` on the component definition's `methods` along with the method's name:

```js
import MyComponent from '@/components/MyComponent.vue'

it('should fetch after clicking on that specific button', async () => {
  const spyFetchRequest = sinon.spy(MyComponent.methods, 'fetchRequest')

  const wrapper = shallowMount(MyComponent)

  ...

  expect(spyFetchRequest.calledOnce).to.be.true
})
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-spy-methods-with-sinon-afepnx?file=tests%2Funit%2FMyComponent.spec.ts)

Comment: @MattSom Fixed the demo link. Do it *before* creating the wrapper. The wrapper will use the mocked/spied method as your click handler.